# iconv settings in php.ini for utf-8 site

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, localization

My php.ini file contains the following:

```
[iconv]
;iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1
```

I want my site to be fully utf-8 enabled.  Any reason why I shouldn't just set those to `UTF-8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iconv lib does not depend on your site but on your OS standard encoding. Take a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/iconv.configuration.php). Anyway, if you do not plan to use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), you do not need to touch these.